# two dataFrame i need to match between two columns and get the coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace, coordinates

i have two data Frame, First have two columns called  PuLocation and DoLocation and contain on a zone number and another data frame contain on a coordinates 'Logtitude' and 'latitude' for all zone number
so, how can i replace PuLocation and DoLocation by coordinated log and lat?? 'In python'

i tried many times but the error :

```
ValueError: Replacement lists must match in length. Expecting 260 got 265
```

first data frame:
[image]

second data frame:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the expected result ?

Comment: what is the mapping between (PULocationID, DOLocationID) and (lattitude, longitude)?